# Highcharts filter string x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does anyone know if its possible to have a string filter for values on the x-axis? For instance, in Google Charts there is a control called ["String Filter"](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#stringfilter)!

Do I need to create my own control using jquery to take the value typed into the input box and systematically remove x-axis values as the user types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not supported, but you can try to use [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) and after input typing, call this function and update your labels on xAxis.